# except not working when using for same table in sql

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

```
select u1 from p1 
where (added_on >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
EXCEPT
select u1 from p1 
where (added_on >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY) 
AND (added_on <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

I tried MINUS, not in and not exists also,they are not working except union
Please help me with this

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? could you present a small example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query, hope you will get desired results-

```
SELECT u1 FROM 
p1 AS p1 
LEFT JOIN p1 AS p2 ON p1.u1=p2.u1 
WHERE p1.added_on >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND p2.added_on >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) 
AND p2.added_on < SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND p2.u1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: actually both table are same so how can p1.primary key = p2.primary key is possible..

Comment: actually what i want to do is if some one added something a day before and the same person added something  in 14 day span of the day before then i do not want to count that same person in a day before data

Comment: left join will contain matched rows also so it wont remove them..and one more thing if a user added 2 times ,it will create 2 enteries so i want to remove duplicate data too.

Comment: first we will get 2 results set then remove matching rows from right result set means now we will be getting only non-matching rows from left result set means only new user..can remove duplicate by distinct ....are you not getting desired results...if you can create a sqlfilddle then I can chec.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT `p1`.`user_id` FROM 
u1 AS p1 
WHERE p1.added_on >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND `p1`.`user_id` NOT IN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT  `p2`.`user_id` FROM 
u1 AS p2 
WHERE p2.added_on >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) 
AND p2.added_on < SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) )

Comment: this query will provide same results as i have posted but left join will provide better performance in case of heavy tables...

Comment: its returning empty result, I am not sure,it is returning correct result or not

Comment: to cross check your results first get unique users from 1st condition and then by 2nd condition and then you can match in excel by vlookup function.

Comment: btw how urs post will remove matching rows? u r putting join on the basis of p1.u1 = p2.u2

Comment: by p2.u1 is null...as for matching rows it will not be NULL.

Comment: I think you have forget to accept this as an answer...:)